# Using different views for full nodes depending on contenttype

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, nodes, drupal-content-types

Think of 2 contenttypes (film, project). I have the homepage showing a few nodes of both. When clicking on a node i get the single node page (url of the node e.g. node/14).

I managed to output the single node page with views (path: node/% and contextual filter). But this is for all nodes regardless of what contenttype the node is. 'film' has different fields than 'project' so i need different views showing single nodes for each contenttype.

Is this possible?

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: I think i dont realy get this question, but whats about a simple filter for content type, e.g. Content: Type (= film) in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Just use - except from the Nid Contextual Filter - a **Filter Criteria** for each content type.

**Filter Criteria > Content: type**

[image: Views Filter Criteria > Content: type]

Comment: @OliverWild Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Page module, and create a page and 2 variants, one for the film and one for project and put condition in context menu.
Other option will be to create 2 template pages for each type of node. The name of each file should be node--node_type_name.tpl.php